# Is there a URL I can post to my geoserver that confirms that I properly installed the GDAL plugin?

Tags: geoserver, gdal, unit-testing

I'm running geoserver in Tomcat and went through the process of installing the plugin for GDAL formats.  I specifically need NITF.

Is there a URL I can post to my geoserver that confirms that I properly installed the GDAL plugin?

Comment: can't check just now but http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/global.html#global-settings might do it

Answer (score 1):

Found it thanks to iant's comment...

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/about/manifest.xml?manifest=gs-gdal-.*
```